Fine-tuning BERT with deterministic masking instead of random masking
I want to fine-tune BERT on a specific dataset. My problem is that I do not want to mask some tokens of my training dataset randomly, but I already have chosen which tokens I want to mask (for certain reasons).
To do so, I created a dataset that has two columns: text in which some tokens have been replaced with [MASK] (I am aware of the fact that some words could be tokenised with more than one token and I took care of that) and label where I have the whole text.
Now I want to fine-tune a BERT model (say, bert-base-uncased) using Hugging Face's transformers library, but I do not want to use  DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm_probability=0.2) where the masking is done randomly and I only can control the probability. What can I do?

This is what I did to solve my problem. I created a custom class and changed the tokenization in a way that I needed (mask one of the numerical spans in the input).
class CustomDataCollator(DataCollatorForLanguageModeling):

    mlm: bool = True
    return_tensors: str = "pt"

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.mlm and self.tokenizer.mask_token is None:
            raise ValueError(
                "This tokenizer does not have a mask token which is necessary "
                "for masked language modeling. You should pass `mlm=False` to "
                "train on causal language modeling instead."
            )

    def torch_mask_tokens(self, inputs, special_tokens_mask):
        """
        Prepare masked tokens inputs/labels for masked language modeling.
        NOTE: keep `special_tokens_mask` as an argument for avoiding error
        """

        # labels is batch_size x length of the sequence tensor
        # with the original token id
        # the length of the sequence includes the special tokens (2)
        labels = inputs.clone()

        batch_size = inputs.size(0)
        # seq_len = inputs.size(1)
        # in each seq, find the indices of the tokens that represent digits
        dig_ids = [1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1020, 1021, 1022, 1023]
        dig_idx = torch.zeros_like(labels)
        for dig_id in dig_ids:
            dig_idx += (labels == dig_id)
        dig_idx = dig_idx.bool()
        # in each seq, find the spans of Trues using `find_spans` function
        spans = []
        for i in range(batch_size):
            spans.append(find_spans(dig_idx[i].tolist()))
        masked_indices = torch.zeros_like(labels)
        # spans is a list of lists of tuples
        # in each tuple, the first element is the start index
        # and the second element is the length
        # in each child list, choose a random tuple
        for i in range(batch_size):
            if len(spans[i]) > 0:
                idx = torch.randint(0, len(spans[i]), (1,))
                start, length = spans[i][idx[0]]
                masked_indices[i, start:start + length] = 1
            else:
                print("No digit found in the sequence!")
        masked_indices = masked_indices.bool()

        # We only compute loss on masked tokens
        labels[~masked_indices] = -100

        # change the input's masked_indices to self.tokenizer.mask_token
        inputs[masked_indices] = self.tokenizer.mask_token_id

        return inputs, labels

def find_spans(lst):
    spans = []
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), key=itemgetter(1)):
        if k:
            glist = list(g)
            spans.append((glist[0][0], len(glist)))

    return spans


probably you want domain specific adaption of BERT.
so far i also could not find customized masking.
but i found this paper useful
PERL: Pivot-based Domain Adaptation for Pre-trained Deep
Contextualized Embedding Models
if any one has a way around to customized masking for BertForMaskedLM
please guide
